# если js отключен, подключаем php

Tags: php, javascript

Вообщем суть такая, на сайте ведутся логи,
js определяет разрешение экрана и отправляет обработчику на php,
который заносит в логи все данные о пользователе.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$.post('/log.php', { width: screen.width, height:screen.height }, function(json) {
   if(json.outcome == 'success') {
       // запрос прошёл успешно
   }
 },'json');
});
```

но если js у пользователя отключен?

Как за одну загрузку страницы, получить переменную php с разрешением экрана, (если разумеется включен js) и тут же отправить, и если js отключен, то оправить без разрешения экрана?

В моем варианте все работает только при включенном js ((

Зачем это нужно?

Кто то скликивает рекламу в яндексе, некотрые клики яндекс считает недействительными, а некоторые проходят. Блокировка по ip не вариант, т.к. у этого провайдера ip динамические, и можно заблокировать не того, поэтому нужно максимум данных, чтобы вовремя внести его в список исключенных, т.е. менять ip

Comment: 90% сайтов в мире не работают без js. Пользователей, которые отключают js, можно смело игнорировать. Толку от них все равно ноль.

Comment: Это рассчитано на злоумышленников, а они как раз таки и могут отключить

Comment: А злоумышленников сразу надо банить, без кодов и раздумий

Comment: а для этого их надо вычислить :)

Comment: Кто то скликивает рекламу в яндексе, некотрые клики яндекс считает недействительными, а некоторые проходят. Блокировка по ip не вариант, т.к. у этого провайдера ip динамические, и можно заблокировать не того, поэтому нужно максимум данных, чтобы вовремя внести его в список исключенных

Comment: Мне кажется, тут вопрос не в кодинге, а в логике. Приходит некто с выключенным js. Варианта два: никчемный юзер или злоумышленник. На мой взгляд, ответ простой: в бан без раздумий. Потерь ноль.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54850/discussion-between-dikkiy-and-kagg-design).

Answer (score 2):

Как отправить ajax-запрос при отключенном js? Никак.

Что касается размеров экрана, если их заменить на размеры окна браузера (точнее, размеры, отведённые под страницу), то можно использовать css'ные media-запросы:

```css
body { background: url(/screen-size?large); }

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  body { background: url(/screen-size?lte=1200); }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  body { background: url(/screen-size?lte=900); }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body { background: url(/screen-size?lte=600); }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  body { background: url(/screen-size?lte=400); }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
  body { background: url(/screen-size?lte=200); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте блок с оповещение пользователя об необходимости включить js,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    ...
    ...
    <div id="js-warning"> JS ОТКЛЮЧЁН ... </div>
```

прячьте его скриптом

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("js-warning").style.display = "none";
</script>
```

Если js отключен, пользователь получает сообщение с рекомендацией о его включении. Метод старый как лапти, но 100% рабочий.

Не встречал отключенного js лет так 5.

Comment: Есть же <noscript>

Comment: @vp_arth, noscript deprecated и несколько глючит в разных браузерах...

Comment: Только в xhtml, не? https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-noscript-element